# Excel - VBA - Save Data to Access Database

Tags: ms-access, excel, ado, vba

I'm working on excel with VBA and access and i need my system to save its data to an Access database and whenever any new records added, deleted or modified the database should update.

I would like to link my spreadsheet and database using ADO but i couldn't find any online resources to help me with that.

Can you please let me know what i need to now in order to do that and any link that you may know that will be usefull?

Thank you 
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised you are having difficulty finding on-line resources. The topic comes up on Stackoverflow often enough, for example: [Export value from Excel worksheet to Access record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000972/export-value-from-excel-worksheet-to-access-record)